# Is there any serious logic behind the Xcode Organizer bug when screenshot's don't work?

Tags: iphone

I always try to make screenshots of running apps, with a 70% chance that it won't work. There is a green light showing my connected device. Most of the times I have to connect and disconnect like 10 times until it can make a screenshot.

What causes this problem? Must I wait 10 minutes after build? Is there any logic behind this failure?

Comment: If this is indeed a bug in the developer tools, it does no good to complain about it here.  File a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com so it can be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my own experience its completely broken. You may have different results, but using the version of Xcode that ships with the 3.2 SDK I cant take screenshots of the device at all. I' have resorted to using the version of xcode that ships with the 4.0 beta, since screenshots work in that version.

I think you'll just have I wait until they fix it, or do as I do and use the beta just for screenshots.